# How to close the activity from current fragment and go back to previous activity in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I am having multiple `activity` in my android app as well as multiple `fragment` for each `activity`. From a `fragment` of third `activity`, I want to close the third activity on a back press. I have tried using this inside `onDetach()` function.

```
getActivity().finish();
```

This closes the current activity but while opening the same `activity` again, the app crashes.

Comment: plz share your crash log.

Comment: "From a fragment of third activity, I want to close the third activity on a back press."
That is the default behavior. Can you elaborate on your setup that makes this not work by default?

Comment: Actually I am having some other `fragment` in `backstack`, and from that particular `fragment` on clicking back I don't want to go back to those previous fragment, instead I wanna close its `activity` itself.

Answer (score 1):

finish() is the final call before the activity gets garbage collected.

You should either not call this at all since there's no real reason to do so. If you do want to return to it later, you can't. You can only create a new Activity. As for fragments, anything that happens on the parent happens on the fragment too.

If you want to close a specific activity, you have to keep a reference to it somewhere where the fragment can access it. Preferably wrapped in a WeakReference so it won't leak memory.

Comment: fragments should be controlled by activities, but not the other way around. You're building an app that will have inter-dependencies that will make it difficult to manage.

Comment: I tried using an `interface` which is inside fragment and implemented by its activity, so that I can communicate with activity and ask it to close.